# Is there any setting in VS code to use .txt file as .robot, and allow to debug code too

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, robotframework

My code has .txt file instead of .robot files, it is a old code and multiple peoples are working on it using pycharm, so I can't rename files to .robot.

There is a setting in pycharm plugin to treat .txt as .robot, is there something like that in VS code, so I use VS code.

pycharm settings for reference.

[image: Pycharm Setting]

******************** +++++++++++++++++++++ ********************

Upper issue is partially solved by "Robot Framework Intellisense",i.e., .text file is coming as same colored print as .robot file, but I am trying to get debug/run button on tests. "Robot Framework Intellisense" is breaking that for .robot files as well. I am using "Robocorp Code" and "Robot Framework Language Server" to get it working for .robot file. will it be possible to get same functionality for .text file.

[image]

Comment: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=TomiTurtiainen.rf-intellisense

Comment: use the setting `files.associations` in your workspace `settings.json`

Comment: @Tomerikoo With "Robot Framework Intellisense", .text file is coming as same colored print as .robot file, but I am trying to get debug/run button on tests. "Robot Framework Intellisense" is breaking that for .robot files as well. I am using "Robocorp Code" and "Robot Framework Language Server" to get it working for .robot file. will it be possible to get same functionality for .text file. Please see the updated question.

Comment: Hello, your second request can't be satisfied at present. I try to submit it to GitHub, but they seem unwilling to deal with it ([vscode-Python](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/154378) pushed it to [vscode](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/154321), which means it's an extension problem)